# Validating Static Resources in a Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

Like most web applications mine has static resources that must be part of the deployment or the user receives a 404 response from the server. My thought was to use unit testing to validate two things 1. the resource exists, and 2. the content was not modified. I have tried the following code but it expects (I think) that the files exist in the unit test project.

Solution structure:
WebApplicationProject
  - ...
  - public
    - file.*
    - otherfile.*
  - web.config

WebApplicationProject.Tests
  - AssetTests.cs

Am I going about this all wrong, should this not be part of a unit test and some other gait on the CI build process (Azure DevOps), or am I missing something super obvious? I'm likely asking the wrong questions and going about this the wrong way, because I know I'm not the first person to want to do something like this.

I've read other posts around testing with files, but they all are using test files to drive data for input in some method that consumes the file, or some process that generates a file for comparison. I don't want to do either of these things.

I have also played with the settings making the file an embedded resource, and to always deploy with the project, but the unit test project still cannot access the file the way I'm going about this.

```
[TestClass]
public class AssetTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem(@".\files\file.*")]
    public void AwardLetters()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "file.*");// gets the working path for the testing dll, no files exist here.
        Assert.IsTrue(File.Exists("file.*"), "FAIL: file {0} not found", "file.*");// nothing I have tried has access to the projects static resources
    }
}
```

All results end in a file not found exception so far.

I did try to load the reference manually using:
    Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom("WebApplicationProject");// also used WebApplicationProject.dll
This fails to find the reference. Yes, the reference property copy local is set to true.

I am open to all suggestions, but if you suggest that I have two copies of the files, please fully explain why this is desirable.

Comment: what does this have to do with unit testing?

Comment: If I can add a unit test here, then when someone changes the file or removes it (like last month) the build will fail the unit test because the resource is missing or changed. If there is a better way please let me know.

The other use case is when someone adds a new file, but forgets to add the file to the CMS, then when the project gets deployed the file gets left out because it's missing.

Comment: I think another way to think about this is: this file is a public static final string, I want a unit test to fail if it doesn't say exactly what it should say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright here's my MVP. I'll leave this open for a while though in hopes someone has a better solution, it cant be this difficult to access the resources like this, I feel like there should be a way to access the applications directory without having to embed the file in the assembly just to pass it to a test method.

```
[TestMethod]
    public void FileExists()
    {
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"..\..\..\WebApplicationProject\bin\WebApplicationProject.dll");
        string t = string.Join("", a.GetManifestResourceNames());
        Assert.IsTrue(t.Contains("file.*"));
    }
```

Now that I have the file I can also create a test to test the content of the file to validate it's contents.

I still think this is duck tape and it's not elegant at all. So please share your answers and critiques of my solution.